# Replace special characters in URL using rewrite rule .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am rewriting my url by using

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search_query=(.+)$ 
RewriteRule ^search/videos$ /search/videos/%1? [R=301,L]
```

from `XXX.XXX.XXX.XX/search/videos?search_query=XXXX+XXXX` to `XXX.XXX.XXX.XX/search/videos/XXXX+XXXX`

now the problem is i want to replace "+" with "-" space (+) with hyphen. I have tried below code but not work.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1-%2 [L,NE,R=302]
```

I have above code to replace space with hyphen, but i want to integrate with below code.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search_query=(.+)$ 
RewriteRule ^search/videos$ /search/videos/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

i have fount the solution on above query i have write rewrite rule like this.

first convert you URL what you want to then you remove the special characters form URL.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search_query=(.+)$ 
RewriteRule ^search/videos$ /search/videos/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R=302]
```